# How to add missing .dll files while preparing .exe file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have just prepared simple script importing some module and printing something:

```
from clicknium import clicknium as cc
print(cc.edge.browsers)
```

So I have created the venv, installed clicknium (pip3 install clicknium==0.1.9).

After that I have prepared spec file:

```
pyi-makespec spec_file_name script_name.py
```

After running the command with created .spec file:

```
pyinstaller spec_file_name.spec
```

The pyinstaller is creating the .exe file.
After running the .exe I got an error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'C:\Users\user_1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI197042\clicknium\.lib\automation\ClickniumJavaBridge-32.dll'
```

Of course I understand the error but I'm not sure how to fix it.

When I has some problems with missing files I have added it by using --add-data while making the spec file. But It's not working for me with .dll files.

clicknium==0.1.9
pyinstaller==5.4.1

### Update

Right now I'm using velow command to create .spec file:

```
pyi-makespec --onefile --add-data="C:\Users\...\project_name\venv\Lib\site-packages\clicknium\.lib\automation\*;clicknium\.lib\automation" --name app app.py
```

The error above is fixed but there is something new.
The code below causes the error:

```
clr.AddReference(Apath)

System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\user_1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEIxxxxxx\clicknium\.lib\automation\ClickniumJavaBridge-32.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

So as I understand the .dll file is still not visible there and clicknium is still looking for the dll files in Temp files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clicknium supplied package project/folder function, can generate the exe.
you can refer to this: https://www.clicknium.com/documents/tutorial/vscode/project_management

first, in vscode, run command "Clicknium: Create Project", you can select the current folder;
then, run command "Clicknium: Package Project", it will generate the exe file

Comment: I have tried it and it's kind working.
I have just problem with some python modules. E.g. the tkinter is not working ("module not found")
Do you maybe know how to fix it? tk should be installed with python

Comment: @tomm Do you need to package a GUI application?

Comment: @Zhiwei yes. The application is using clicknium to get some data from browser.
So when I am using the clicknium project packaging, as justin suggested - I have problem with tkinter.
When I am using the pyinstaller - problem with clicknium .dll's

Comment: @tomm Currently the default package is the console application, we will support the gui application

Comment: @Zhiwei just a question - I have finally converted my application with clicknium and Package Project as you suggested. It's working even with my tk application.
The only one problem is my console window what I want to hide. Do you think, is it possible?

Comment: @tomm The problem has been fixed, the next release will be good  https://thumbs2.imgbox.com/23/38/c5JiBbXW_t.gif

Comment: Oh that's great! So it will be possible to prepare GUI app with no console?

Comment: @tomm yes, The project package will ask you whether you choose a console or GUI kind.

Comment: That's awsome, i will refresh the clicknium release page every day :)
Thank you for the information!

Comment: @tomm New version is released,https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ClickCorp.clicknium/changelog

Comment: Great, testing!

Comment: @Zhiwei the clicknium lib works ok, but I have found some issue.

Comment: @Zhiwei Simple code with some while True and executing "cc.edge.browsers" inside will increase memory usage. So there is something wrong. As I see you are working on the library, I have added the issue to the clicknium github. github.com/clicknium/clicknium-docs/issues/46

Comment: @tomm thanks for the feedback, we will reproduce this issue and update about this.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to add *.dll files to your build process in the *.spec file

Look here, there is a lot of discussion about it:
[Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile?rq=1)

Comment: Hi @flipSTAR, I have looked there before with no success. Please if you can, take a look at the updated post.

Comment: hey, nice update. sorry I can't help with your new error !

Answer (score 0):

If it not work for you try using other options like one file:

```
pyi-makespec -F script_name.py spec_file_name
```

also the order need to be the script first

```
pyi-makespec script_name.py -n spec_file_name
```

Comment: Sorry, I have not added the info that the error occurs when I run the exe file. So pyinstaller is creating the .exe correctly but after running the script I got error that some .dll is missing

Answer (score 0):

When trying to debug any problem with `--onefile` files not being right, try switching to one-folder bundling and it is a lot easier to debug missing files.